Can access environment variable in terminal but not from the script
I'm using Pycharm in windows 11.
I'm creating an environment variable called APP_ID using $env:APP_ID = "12345"
When I run dir env: I can see it.
But running this simple script gives me none:
import os
print(os.environ.get("APP_ID"))

But when I run the script from the terminal (python main.py) it gives me the key 12345.
If I change the script to print(os.environ) and run it it's not there, but if I again run it from the terminal it's there.

(On normal/UNIXy platforms -- you should really be tagging this for Windows since it behaves differently from everywhere else:) Environment variables are inherited from your parent process. It's completely normal for different processes to be able to have different variables defined; if your GUI isn't started from a shell it won't see variables defined via shell dotfiles.

This is a problem with how you're setting the variable in powershell, not how you're retrieving it in Python. As per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_environment_variables?view=powershell-7.4 --

When you change environment variables in PowerShell, the change affects only the current session

To set your variable for your entire user account, not just a single session within it, you should use:
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('APP_ID','12345')


See also https://superuser.com/a/1729961/447008
